# order of events in javascript not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've seen couple of posts on this subject, but quite did not get the answer. I have a onClick event, which calls the Uploadfile() function, only after the Uploadfile() function is called, I want the EnableSaveButton() function to be called. pasted below is the code, I have for the click event, Uploadfile() function and the EnableSaveButton() function. Currently only the Uploadfile() gets called, but the EnableSavebutton() function does not get triggered. Would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

***UPDATE: Let me re-phrase the question. How do I make sure that EnableSaveButton() is called only after, UploadFile() get called. Currently what happens is, EnableSaveButton triggers before UploadFile().

```
$("#btnUploadFile").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    uploadFile();
    EnableSaveButton();

});

function uploadFile() {
    $.get('<%: Url.Action("UploadFile","Files") %>', null, function(getData) {
        $(getData).appendTo('body');
    });
}

function EnableSaveButton() {
    var selectedvalue = $("#FileGuid").val();
    alert(selectedvalue);
    if (selectedvalue != "") {
        $("#btnSave").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    EnableSaveButton();
}
```

This function is declared but not assigned nor used... So your function `EnableSaveButton` is not called.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an anonymous function in your click handler that is never called.

```
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    EnableSaveButton();
}
```

Why you won't just do this:

```
$("#btnUploadFile").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    uploadFile();
    EnableSaveButton();
});
```

Comment: The reason I did'nt do that is because, EnableSaveButton() gets triggered before the UploadFile() function gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the `EnableSaveButton()` function to be called after the `UploadFile()` function completes (or more specifically, after the Ajax call inside the `UploadFile` function completes), correct?

```
$("#btnUploadFile").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            uploadFile();
        });

  function uploadFile() {
        $.get(
            '<%: Url.Action("UploadFile","Files") %>',
            null,
            function (getData) {
                $(getData).appendTo('body');
                EnableSaveButton();
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Correct, exactly, but when I have the EnableSaveButton() function inside the UploadFile() function, the EnableSaveButton() triggers first.

Comment: Thats why in my example I posted, the call to `EnableSaveButton` is part of the "success" function on the `$.get` call.

Comment: I had the same exact code that you had posted, but the EnableSaveButton() triggers before the getData is done

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    EnableSaveButton(); 
}
```

Declares an anonymous function taking one parameter (which is called event). It is then not called anwhere. If you wanted to call your function then you could do:

```
(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    EnableSaveButton(); 
})(event);
```

or:

```
var handler = function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    EnableSaveButton(); 
}
handler();
```

or simpler still:

```
EnableSaveButton();
```

Comment: EnableSaveButton() gets triggered before UploadFile(), I want to make sure that only after Upload() function is done, that the EnableSaveButton() is called.

Comment: Oh I see. Well the issue is that `$.get` is an async method, so it's callback won't happen until it's finished talking to the server. Meanwhile your other method is callled. Either specify the other method in the callback or use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set `async` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

So why not call EnableSaveButton as a callback to the ajax code that uploads the file.
I use this technique all the time. 
An ajax request gets some data and dumps it into the page, a user-defined callback is then performed for adjusting scroll-bars, form-elements etc.